# keep master branch without deleted code after merging

Tags: android, git, mercurial, merge

I have two branches, the development and the master.

Code in master branch can't have Log calls, comments, etc . Everything else is the same.
So when I merged to the master before commit I deleted everything I didn't want.

I continued developing on development branch and now I want to merge and commit the changes **but** I guess that will add again what I have previous deleted.

Is there a way to commit only the changes from the development branch or a workflow/solution for this problem ?

I'm using mercurial but I guess someone who is facing the same problem with git can help.
I'm new with mercurial and don't know much about git.

Thank you

Comment: this you should take care in the logger or config area of your code, no VCS can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you need to find a different method for tracking/sharing such items but if that is impossible then you could possibly use python hooks to filter them out of any commits to your master branch.

See [this](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) chapter of the hgbook for some discussion of some of the possibilities.